# How to find counterfeit coins?

Tags: combinatorics

Of 101 coins, 50 are counterfeit and differ from the genuine coins by 1 gram. All of the 50 counterfeit coins weight the same amount. Natalia has a scale in the form of a balance which shows the difference in weights between the objects placed in each pan. She chooses one coin and wants to find out in one weighing whether it is counterfeit. Can she do this?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried with a smaller number, like 3 good and 2 counterfeit?

Comment: Yes, weigh the other 50 vs 50. Odd or even?

Comment: Interesting.  As a meta-puzzle if there *is* a solution it can't be one where you put the coin with another coin (you wouldn't be able to distinguish it fro the other coins).  If you put it on one side of the scale then you can only put one in the other and that won't tell you anything as you don't know if the other is real.  So the only option is to leave the coin out and measure the other 100.  So that's *how* the question is how to interpret it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the scale registers the absolute value of the difference (though I don't think that changes what follows in a significant way).

Take the remaining $100$ coins and weigh $50$ against $50$.  Let $N$ be the difference between the weights.

Case I:  the chosen coin is real.  In that case there are $50$ real and $50$ fake amongst the $100$ that you weighed.  Say the left hand contains $a$ fake and $50-a$ real. Then the right hand contains $50-a$ fake and $a$ real.  Say each fake weighs one more than a real.  In that case the left hand weights $50n+a$ and the right hand weighs $50n+50-a$ so we have $$N=|a-50-a|=|2a-50|$$  If the fake weighs one less than a real we see that the left hand weighs $50n-a$ and the right weighs $50n-50+a$ so again $$N=|-a-a+50|=|2a-50|$$

Case II.  the chosen coin is fake.  In that case there are $49$ fake and $51$ real.  If there are $a$ fake and $50-a$ real coins on the left, then there are $49-a$ fake and $a+1$ real on the right.  Again, assuming the fake weighs one more than the real we that the left weighs $50n+a$ while the right weighs $50n+49-a$.  Thus $$N=|a-49+a|=|2a-49|$$ again, this is also the case if a fake coin weighs one less.

We note that in case I, $N$ is always even and in case II it is always odd, so we are done.

Comment: You are a fast typer!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at it a bit differently, there is definitely a 'technical solution'. Sorry if anyone disagrees with this method.

First, let us see our cases.

Let the weight of a genuine(legal) coin be equal to L grams.
Then there are 2 cases for the total weight of the 101 coins,
when counterfeit is heavier: 101L+50, grams, and when it is light:101L-50 grams.

So, what I'm assuming is that, when weighing, she first places her coin on one side, sees the difference on the machine(assumption-machine instantly shows the difference, no need to press a switch to see a difference as then this would count as 2 weighings) which is equal to the weight of her coin.

Case1 total weight =101L+50 grams.

Sub case 1a: her coin weighs L, other pile(of remaining 100 coins) weighs 100L+50

Sub case 1b: her coin weighs L+1, and the other pile weighs 100L+49

Case 2 total weight =101L-50 grams.

Sub case 2a: her coin weighs L, other pile weighs 100L-50

Sub case 2b: her coin weighs L-1, other pile weighs 100L-49.

Difference in weights of 1a:99L+50

Difference in 1b: 99L+48

In 2a:99L-50

In 2b:99L-48.

Now, if she multiplies the weight of her coin by 99, she gets:

In case 1a: 99L

In 1b: 99L+99

In 2a:99L

In 2b:99L-99

Comparing 99x(Weight of her coin) to Difference between piles, we see that difference between 1)99x(Weight of her coin) and 2) Difference between the weights of the two piles is

(99xHer)-(Diff. b/w piles)=

99L-(99L+50)= -50 in 1a

(99L+99)-(99L+48)= +51 in 1b

99L-(99L-50)= +50 in 2a

(99L-99)-(99L-48)= -51 in 2b

Based on this difference, she can tell which case it is, 1a,1 b,2a or 2b. If it is 1a or 2a then, her coin is the genuine thing. If it is 1b, her coin is a counterfeit and the counterfeits are heavier. If it is 2b, her coin is a counterfeit and counterfeits are lighter.

So if you consider this as one weighing, yes she can tell but, if you consider this as two weighings then there must be a better solution.

Edit: That beter solution just got posted while I was typing.